# Add solicitation into the spam flag

Tags: feature-request, flags, spam, advertising

While looking at the flag review queue in the 10k tools I came across this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22516102/1026459

> Daniel. I would like to talk to you about the Betty Boop project. Where is an appropriate place to talk about that? Maybe you could email me? xxxxxxxx@hotmail.com Thanks.

That was the entire answer (I added x's because it isn't about that person but about this pattern).

I think solicitation is also spamish, it is definitely in the same ballpark as an advertisement. Perhaps the spam flag could also include this type of activity (and also include the same negative connotation of receiving the spam flag).

> This answer is effectively solicitation or an advertisement with no disclosure. It is not useful or relevant, but promotional.

The request is to group solicitation with advertisement in the spam flag. My specific suggestion is to add the words "solicitation or" in the text of the flag.

Comment: Well... do we really need another flag for this? It is a typical NAA afterall...

Comment: @hichris123 - This isn't another flag, just a small wording modification to cover this pattern. It is not a typical NAA, it is a solicitation. It will add more weight into the post ban.

Comment: You might want to keep an eye on the person who posted that, FYI. They just posted another one...

Comment: I don't know if they're so much a spammer as they are someone who's a little misguided and wanting to contact the person asking the question. I've protected the question to prevent them from asking again, and left them a note, but I'm holding off on destroying their account and feeding them into the anti-spam system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't really look like spam to me.

In fact, it doesn't really look like solicitation to me, either, at least not in the usual sense.  What it *does* look like is simply someone trying to contact a former acquaintance / collaborator / business partner by unusual means, presumably after more conventional methods had failed.  It's still not what Stack Overflow is supposed to be used for, but it's at least somewhat understandable.

(Of course, it *could* be just really sneaky actual spam, but that seems kind of unlikely.)

Still, even if the answer *had* been solicitation in the usual sense (e.g. "Hi, I saw your post here and thought you might be interested in this project I'm working on..."), I still wouldn't flag it as spam.  The thing is, [spam flags on SE are rather heavy and blunt instruments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work/58035#58035), designed to allow a quick and thorough virtual bludgeoning of clearly malicious abusers of the site.  They're not exactly subtle, or good for dealing with borderline cases.

While a message like I described above *would* technically satisfy some definitions of spam, I'd rather prefer to start off by assuming good faith, and just flag it as "not an answer", maybe with a comment suggesting that the user try [Careers 2.0](http://careers.stackoverflow.com) instead.

Of course, that's assuming that it was a one-off (or two-off) incident — if the user kept literally spamming such answers to dozens of questions, then a real spam flag would indeed be appropriate.

Comment: Every time this pattern arises, it seems to follow spam. Here is another example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21112702/1026459 . Note the various abuses of the system by the user. 2 duplicate posts in the same day, an email contact as an answer, and no closures or flags that caught any of it.

Comment: @TravisJ: I still don't see a good reason to assume malice where simple ignorance is a sufficient explanation. *We* all know that you're not supposed to post non-answers to reply to existing answers, nor to ask for further info by e-mail, but newbies who are more used to discussion forums do that all the time. Usually, a simple polite comment will suffice to educate them.

Comment: That user has been a member for 1 year and 9 months. The point is that this should run them into the content ban faster than just slowly getting there. As shown by the example in my post here, slowly getting there tends to be repeating the same behavior.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean they're familiar with the site -- it just means they asked a question once, got an answer, went away, and came back to ask another one 1.5 years later. I bet this guy logs in via Google or Facebook, or has their SE password saved in their browser; otherwise, they'd have just created a new account, and you wouldn't even know it wasn't their first ever visit here.

Comment: Those 3 actions were their only contributions (and they were recent). They aren't being removed from the site, just from posting bad content, or at least potentially if it gets bad enough. Pure solicitation in an answer is a clear disregard of convention. After 1.75 years they probably have at least read something about posting.

Comment: Why would they have, if they've only visited the site less than a dozen times in those 1.75 years? (I don't *know* that that's the case, since I'm not a mod, but it seems very likely.) People do that, you know: ask a question, get an answer, go away satisfied. Occasionally, if they happen to have another question later, they may even do it a second time. Folks like you and me, who stick around, visit the site often, actually get to know the community norms and actively look for topics to participate in, we're very much unusual outliers.